# mcmapply performance on multiple cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mapply, mclapply

I have a function which I want to run on around 3 million datapoints. I am trying to parallelise the function using `mcmapply` on a **Ubuntu** machine with 8 cores. The function takes in a `list` of length 3 million as well as 3 more vectors of length 3 million and 1 constant value `cutoffyearmon`.

The code runs perfectly fine with 100000 rows of data within 2 minutes on a single core and throws no error. However, when I try to run the code in parallel on 6 cores of my machine using `mcmapply` it keeps on running for more than 5 hours.

**UPDATE: This is the watered down version of my function call. There are 9 more variables which I create for time duration of 1month, 2month and 3month. I have taken variables for time 6month and 1year only.**

I am using the following function call:

```
abc_xx_last_xxx_days=mcmapply(function(abcstrnew,sd,naflag,empflag,daysdiff,cutoffyearmon){
abcstrnew=if((!naflag) & (!empflag)){
    substring(text = abcstrnew,first = seq(from = 1,to = (nchar(abcstrnew)-2),by = 3),last = seq(from = 3,to = (nchar(abcstrnew)),by = 3))
}else{
    if(!is.na(empflag) & empflag){
        ""
    }else{
        NA_character_
    }
}

abcstrnew=if((!naflag) & (!empflag)){
    as.numeric(abcstrnew)
}else{
    if(!is.na(empflag) & empflag){
        as.numeric(0)
    }else{
        NA_real_
    }
}
if(is.na(daysdiff)){
  return(list(worst_abc_ever=NA_real_,
              times_abc=NA_real_,
              times_abc_last_180_days=NA_real_,
              times_abc_last_365_days=NA_real_,
              times_abc30_last_365_days=NA_real_,
              times_abc30_last_180_days=NA_real_,
              times_abc60_last_365_days=NA_real_,
              times_abc60_last_180_days=NA_real_,
              abc_last_180_days=NA_real_,
              abc_last_365_days=NA_real_
  ))
}else{
  if((!naflag)&(!empflag)){
    abcstrlen=length(abcstrnew)
    worst_abc_ever=max(abcstrnew)
    times_abc=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew>0)))

    if(daysdiff>365){
      abc_last_365_days=as.numeric(0)
      times_abc30_last_365_days=as.numeric(0)
      times_abc60_last_365_days=as.numeric(0)
      times_abc_last_365_days=as.numeric(0)
    }else{
      abcmonthstwelve=12-round(round(difftime(time1 = cutoffyearmon,time2 = as.yearmon(sd)))/30)

      if(abcstrlen>=abcmonthstwelve){
        abc_last_365_days=(max(abcstrnew[1:abcmonthstwelve]))
      }else{
        abc_last_365_days=(max(abcstrnew[1:abcstrlen]))
      }


      if(abcstrlen>=abcmonthstwelve){
        times_abc30_last_365_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcmonthstwelve]>=30)))
      }else{
        times_abc30_last_365_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcstrlen]>=30)))
      }


      if(abcstrlen>=abcmonthstwelve){
        times_abc60_last_365_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcmonthstwelve]>=60)))
      }else{
        times_abc60_last_365_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcstrlen]>=60)))
      }


      if(abcstrlen>=abcmonthstwelve){
        times_abc_last_365_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcmonthstwelve]>0)))
      }else{
        times_abc_last_365_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcstrlen]>0)))
      }
    }


    if(daysdiff>180){
      abc_last_180_days=as.numeric(0)
      times_abc30_last_180_days=as.numeric(0)
      times_abc60_last_180_days=as.numeric(0)
      times_abc_last_180_days=as.numeric(0)
    }else{
      abcmonthssix=6-round(round(difftime(time1 = cutoffyearmon,time2 = as.yearmon(sd)))/30)

      if(abcstrlen>=abcmonthssix){
        abc_last_180_days=(max(abcstrnew[1:abcmonthssix]))
      }else{
        abc_last_180_days=(max(abcstrnew[1:abcstrlen]))
      }


      if(abcstrlen>=abcmonthssix){
        times_abc30_last_180_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcmonthssix]>=30)))
      }else{
        times_abc30_last_180_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcstrlen]>=30)))
      }


      if(abcstrlen>=abcmonthssix){
        times_abc60_last_180_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcmonthssix]>=60)))
      }else{
        times_abc60_last_180_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcstrlen]>=60)))
      }


      if(abcstrlen>=abcmonthssix){
        times_abc_last_180_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcmonthssix]>0)))
      }else{
        times_abc_last_180_days=as.numeric(length(which(abcstrnew[1:abcstrlen]>0)))
      }

    }

    return(list(worst_abc_ever=worst_abc_ever,
                times_abc=times_abc,
                times_abc_last_180_days=times_abc_last_180_days,
                times_abc_last_365_days=times_abc_last_365_days,
                times_abc30_last_365_days=times_abc30_last_365_days,
                times_abc30_last_180_days=times_abc30_last_180_days,
                times_abc60_last_365_days=times_abc60_last_365_days,
                times_abc60_last_180_days=times_abc60_last_180_days,
                abc_last_180_days=abc_last_180_days,
                abc_last_365_days=abc_last_365_days
    ))
  }else{
    return(list(worst_abc_ever=NA_real_,
                times_abc=NA_real_,
                times_abc_last_180_days=NA_real_,
                times_abc_last_365_days=NA_real_,
                times_abc30_last_365_days=NA_real_,
                times_abc30_last_180_days=NA_real_,
                times_abc60_last_365_days=NA_real_,
                times_abc60_last_180_days=NA_real_,
                abc_last_180_days=NA_real_,
                abc_last_365_days=NA_real_
    ))
  }
}
},lst,sd,naflag,empflag,daysdiff,cutoffyearmon,mc.cores=6, mc.preschedule=TRUE, mc.cleanup=TRUE)
```

You can use the following set of inputs to run the function and check it's output.

```
lst=list("000050000032","000000340000000000000")
sd=c(as.Date.character("2017-05-22"),as.Date.character("2017-04-23"))
empflag=c(FALSE,FALSE)
naflag=c(FALSE,FALSE)
daysdiff=difftime(time1 = as.Date.character("2017-06-30"),time2 = sd)
cutoffyearmon=as.yearmon("2017-06-30")
```

I am assuming the code will divide the data almost equally between 6 cores by assigning `mc.preschedule=TRUE`. But I am not able to see any significant performance in the processing speed. I am expecting the processing to be completed in around 1.5 hours when run on 6 cores of the machine.

Any suggestions if I have missed something.

**When using pbmcmapply with `mc.cores=6` I am getting an ETA of 06:01:32:57**

Comment: Impossible to assess with the amount of information you provide. Possibly the system starts swapping because RAM is exhausted?

Comment: @Roland What additional information can I provide? I have 32GB RAM machine.

Comment: Does the system start swapping?

Comment: @RalfStubner No it does not.

Comment: @Roland I have updated my function completely here. Please take a look if possible.

Comment: @tushaR Did you find a solution? I have the same problem when using `mlr` package's random search to find optimal parameters (for xgboost model). In the backend it works with `mcmapply` as well. I run this on Ubuntu as well. It takes way longer than it should (than it performed on a much weaker laptop)

Comment: @Corel: Unfortunately no. I felt that parallelisation with `data.table` package does not work well. My intuition could be wrong. I vectorised my function and that gave a significant timing boost without using the parallel packages.